# get x64 process module base address from x86 app

Tags: windows, winapi

How would one get the base address of a module in a x64 process from a x86(32bit) app. i have no problem getting the process id with `NtQuerySystemInformation` but `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` and `EnumProcesses` both fail to get the x64 process modules, are there any other ways to do this like any undocumented functions im missing?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be so much easier to do this in a 64 bit process as intended by the designers of the system?

Comment: Please show your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by parsing PEB structure. It's undocumented but it's not changing between systems: http://www.nirsoft.net/kernel_struct/vista/PEB.html

Interesting part for you is PEB->Ldr->InLoadOrderModuleList.